# DNS caching with BG updates

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system

I am looking for a solution for Ubuntu server to use DNS caching that.

- if it has the record and is not expired (either in cache or in local definitions) return the record
- if it **has** the record **and is expired, returns the record** and **in the background updates the local entry
- if it is not found queries upstream

The most important bit is to return quickly even the possibly non valid record, but do not wait for the dns resolution.

Could this be done by configuring bind/dnsmasq and how or would it be better to create custom solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a solution which does exactly what you ask for but for instance [Unbound](https://unbound.net/) has an option to prefetch data for cache entries that are about to expire.

From [unbound.conf(5)](https://unbound.net/documentation/unbound.conf.html):

```
   prefetch: <yes or no>
          If yes, message cache elements are prefetched before they expire
          to keep the cache up to date.  Default is  no.   Turning  it  on
          gives about 10 percent more traffic and load on the machine, but
          popular items do not expire from the cache.
```

While this is not the same approach that you describe in the question it seems that it should meet the same overall goal.